# How is ProvisionedThroughput calculated in DynamoDB when using transaction?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We have a dynamodb table with write capacity of 1,000, but it suffers from `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded` when writing an batch around 170 items within one transaction to the db.

According to the [design doc](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions/blob/master/DESIGN.md), 
`As implemented, this protocol requires 7N+4 writes`, does it mean the writing for 170 items within one transaction actually take 7*170+4 = 1194 units of writing?

Answer (score 0):

### The following answer is from Pavol Zibrita (zibrita).

Almost. It means you will have 1194 writes for 170 items. However, for number of units (write capacity), it depends on the item size and how fast you are writing to dynamodb. From doc:

```
1 write capacity unit per item × 100 writes per second = 100 write capacity units
```

and 1 unit is for 1KB of data, so:

```
1.5 KB / 1 KB = 1.5 --> 2 units
```

That means, if your items are 1.5KB, you need 2 units to write 1 item. If you would do the whole batch in 1 second, which is 1194 writes, you would actually need 1194x2 units. (I'm not however sure, how big are the items that the transaction library needs to write, they might be actually small, so consuming only 1 unit)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html#HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.Writes

you can also consider:

https://github.com/sebdah/dynamic-dynamodb